# Finding solutions to $x + y = xy$ where $x > y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Finding solutions (no matter real or complex) for $x$ and $y$.

$$ x + y = xy$$

Where $x > y$.

Is this possible?

If I try to substitute 1 for $x$, it turns out:
\begin{align}
(1) + y &= (1)y\\
y + 1 &= y\\
y - y = -1\\
0 ≠ -1\\
\end{align}

EDIT: For complex solutions, disregard the condition $ x > y$

Comment: There's an easy way to find such solutions. You got the only case where the solution is not defined. Anyway, what does it means $x>y$ for complex numbers??

Comment: Take, fro example, any $y \in (1,2)$ and define $x$ to be $\frac y {y-1}$.

Comment: You say "no matter real or complex" but then you require $x>y$. That doesn't make sense for complex numbers.

Comment: @Murthy It breaks the condition $x > y$...

Comment: You may rewrite the constraints as $(x-1)(y-1)=1$ and $x-1>y-1$. This should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider 
$$
A^2 - u A + u = 0,
$$
where $u = x+y =xy$, then $x,y$ are the roots of the equation above about $A$. $x >y$ implies $x, y \in \mathbb R$ [for complex numbers, we could define $<$, but none of them can guarantee that each pair $(x,y)$ is comparable ]. Then the discriminant
$$
u^2 - 4u > 0 \iff u < 0 \vee u >4.
$$
So to get one solution, pick some $u > 4$, say $u = 8$, then solve the quadratic, we have 
$$
x = 4+2\sqrt 2, y = 4-2\sqrt 2. 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Solving for y:
$$y=\dfrac{x}{x-1}$$
You want $x\gt y$ so.
$$x\gt\dfrac{x}{x-1}$$
and you get:
$x\gt 2$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that gives the exhaustive set of solutions.

Equation $$x+y=xy \ \text{with constraint} \ x>y, \tag{1}$$

with the following change of variables (see the remark by @user1551):

$$x=u+1 \ \text{and} \ y=v+1 \tag{2}$$

is equivalent to the simpler problem:

$$uv=1  \ \text{with constraint} \ u>v \tag{3}$$

(the constraint on $u$ and $v$ is due to $x>y \iff x-1>y-1$).

Thus it suffices to consider

- either any $0<v<1$ ; the ordered pair $(u=\frac{1}{v},v)$ is a solution.
- or any $v<-1$ ; the ordered pair $(u=\frac{1}{v},v)$ is a solution.
- there are no other solutions, because other choices for $v$ give $u<v$.

Then switch back to variables $x,y$ using (2).

One can see a way to interpret what we do in terms of a supplementary image : (quadric) surface $z=xy$ intersected by plane with  equation $z=1$ along the hyperbola whose horizontal projection has equation $y=\frac{1}{x}$.

[image]

Remark : you cannot have complex solutions because $x>y$ doesn't make sense in $\mathbb{C}$.